# How can I make GCC/Clang warn about the use of uninitialized members?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, warnings

I am compiling the code behind

```
class Test {
public:
    Test() {}

    int k;
};

int main() {
  Test t;
  std::cout << t.k << "\n";
}
```

like

```
g/clang++ main.cpp -Wall -Wextra --std=c++14 -o exe; ./exe
```

Why neither of the compilers does not warn me about indeterminate value of the integer is not it a very serious potential bug? How to enable a warning for indeterminate initializations?

Comment: Compilers are not required and often are not capable of detecting and reporting cases of undefined behavior. Perhaps you will need to utilize more sophisticated static analysis tools.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this example, GCC [gives me the desired warning](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/46f5e8b170169266) when I give it `-O1` (or higher).

Presumably whatever mechanism it uses to detect this is tied into the optimisation effort level somehow. [It's a notoriously hard thing to do](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Better_Uninitialized_Warnings).

Ensure that you heed your release-build warnings as well as debug-build warnings.